# Getting time and space complexity of a JS function

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, space-complexity

Here' i have a solution of a problem of removing consecutive duplicate characters. But i need to know the time and space complexity of this solution.

Here's the function:

```js
function removeAdjacentDuplicates(str){
    for (let i = 0; i< str.length -1; i++){
        if(str[i] === str[i+1] && i+2==str.length){
            return str.substr(0,i);
        } else if(i+2==str.length ||str=="" || str.length==0){
            return str;
        } else if (str[i] === str[i+1]){
            return removeAdjacentDuplicates(str.substr(0,i)+str.substr(i+2,(str.length)-(i+2))); 
        }
    }
};

//removeAdjacentDuplicates('abbc') returns 'ac'
```

I'm guessing it should be O(n) for both because for each input the function needs to loop over the whole. Also suggestion for making the function better would be appreciated too.

Comment: Please explain further, what do you mean by time and space complexity?

Comment: Where is `match` function and what does it do?

Comment: Updated the question. The result is shown as comment in the question. @decpk

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve that question? where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose a simple [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) will be sufficient and [not too complex](https://dev.to/lukocastillo/time-complexity-big-0-for-javascript-array-methods-and-examples-mlg) here.

How to determine complexity is [explained nicely here](https://medium.com/dataseries/how-to-calculate-time-complexity-with-big-o-notation-9afe33aa4c46). Furthermore, there are plenty of articles to be found on the subject (e.g. [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/big-o-notation-why-it-matters-and-why-it-doesnt-1674cfa8a23c/) or [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/complexity-analysis/time-and-space-complexity/tutorial/)).

[See also](https://js-2dv3eu.stackblitz.io)

```js
console.log(`original: abba and,, sommmme of thaat ook??`, ` `);
console.log(`removeAdjacentDuplicates: ${
  removeAdjacentDuplicates('abba and,, sommmme of thaat ook??')}`);
console.log(`removeDuplicateCharacterPairs: ${
  removeDuplicateCharacterPairs('abba and,, sommmme of thaat ook??')}`);
console.log(`RemoveConcurrentCharacters: ${
    RemoveConcurrentCharacters([...'abba and,, sommmme of thaat ook??'])}`);
console.log(`RemoveConcurrentCharactersReducer: ${
  RemoveConcurrentCharactersReducer([...'abba and,, sommmme of thaat ook??'])}`);

// this removes one of duplicate character pairs
function removeAdjacentDuplicates(str) {
  return str.split('')
    .reduce((acc, val) =>
      val === acc.slice(-1) ? acc : acc + val, '');
}

// this removes actual duplicate pairs, 
// but the result may contain new duplicates
function removeDuplicateCharacterPairs(str, result = []) {
  str = str.split("");
  const first = str.shift();
  str.length && first !== str[0] && result.push(first) || str.shift();
  return str.length ?
    removeDuplicateCharacterPairs(str.join(""), result) :
    result.join("");
}

// this removes duplicate pairs. When the result
// contains new duplicate pairs removes them too
// so the result will not contain any duplicate
// character pair
function RemoveConcurrentCharacters(arr) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    const len = result.length - 1;

    i < 1 && result.push(arr[i]);

    if (i > 0) {
      arr[i] !== result[len] &&
        result.push(arr[i]) ||
        result.splice(len, 1);
    }
  }
  return result.join("");
};

// making a round trip: RemoveConcurrentCharacters can be
// condensed using a reducer method.
function RemoveConcurrentCharactersReducer(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, val) =>
      !acc.length ? [val] : val === acc[acc.length-1] ? 
        acc.slice(0, -1) : [...acc, val], [])
    .join("");
};
```

Comment: Your solution keeps one character from the duplicate characters. My solution actually removes characters if two of them are adjacant and duplicate. ('abbba' returns 'aba' & 'abba' returns 'aa'). It would be great if you could do that to your solutution @Kooilnc

Comment: Looks like a matter of language - I presumed you wanted to keep one of the duplicates because of the function name (`removeAdjacentDuplicates` => remove [only] the _adjacent_  duplicate values). May be me not being a native english speaker. Added a function that removes _all_ pairs of duplicate characters recursively.